# Trying to parse JSON file with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I am trying to parse a JSON file with the exact stucture as in the following.

```
{
    "students": {
        "student": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "John Doe",
                "image": "pic1.jpg",
                "homepage": "http: //www.google.com"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Jane Doe",
                "image": "pic1.jpg",
                "homepage": "http: //www.google.com"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am using the following jQuery function:

```
function GetStudents(filename)
{
    $.getJSON(filename, function(data){
        $.each(data.student, function(i,s){
            var id = s.id;;
            var name = s.name;;
            var img = s.image;;
            var homepage = s.homepage;
            $('.networkTable').append('<tr><td><img src="' + img + '" class="picEven pic" width="33" height="35"></td><td><a href="'+ homepage + '" class="networkLink">' + name + '</a></td></tr>');
        });
    });
}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: It should be `$.each(data.students.student,...`. Does this help? If not then there might be a problem retrieving the data. Are you reading the file from your server or an external one?

Comment: looks like it should be `$.each(data.students.student, /*other code here...*/);`

Comment: Oh yeah, I missed that point by Felix. That could be the true reason.

Comment: That solved the issue :D. Thank you very much, i struggled with this the entire day :(

Comment: @Felix: You should post your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not accessing the correct element. `data` does not point to `students`, it points to the outer most element `{students:...}` (`students` is an property of it). The array is contained in `data.students.student`:

```
$.each(data.students.student, function() {
    //...
});
```

---

Further notes:

- You don't need to create a local variable if you access a property only once (but of course it might be more readable).
- While having consecutive semicolons `;;` is not wrong, it is unnecessary and confusing (at least it confuses me ;))

Answer (score 1):

```
s.nametry: <br/>
$("document").ready(function() {
    $.getJSON(fileUrl,

    function(data)
    {
        $("#div-my-table").text("&lt;table&gt;");
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            $("#div-my-table").append("&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;" + item.prop1 +"&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;" + item.prop2 + "&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;");
        });
        $("#div-my-table").append("&lt;/table>");
    });
});
```