# Offline mobile application - should i be able to read in a localally stored JSON file?

Tags: json, html, local, offline

My question is similar to the one here [Trying to parse JSON file with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097783/trying-to-parse-json-file-with-jquery) but i don't seem to be able to adapt it.

I want to create an offline mobile app mainly using HTML5, CSS and JavaScript/Jquery
All the files in the app will be cashed I hope when I've it working

I had thought to created a JSON file containing some data about computer labs - eg open hours capasity that type of thing

```
 {  "name":"Boole basement",
"location":"Main Campus",
"staffed":"Yes"}
```

And then read in the localy stored JSON file - parse it or whatever and then display each object in a new div. Initially I was just trying to get the data into one div. heck if I could get the contents of the JSON file to display I'd be delighted!

My HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>
<script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
/* <![CDATA[ */
$(document).ready(function(){
var test =" ";
var filename = "test.json";

$.getJSON(filename, function(json){
    $.each(json.labs, function(i, lab){
        test = lab.name;
        test+=" "+lab.location;
            $('#space').append(test);
            alert("Hi");


        });
   });
});

/* ]]> */
</script>
</head>
<body>

  <h2>available labs:</h2>
  <div id="space">some text</div>

</body>
</html>
```

PS Is what I've discribed even possible...

Answer (score 0):

What you have described is entirely possible, yes. But your code needs work:

For example, your selector for `space` is incorrect (it's an ID in your mark-up, but you're using a **class** selector in your jQuery code).

(**EDIT** OK, I see you've edited your example code now).

Comment: I had been using #space but I get confused by various examples and end up trying things every which way. Even using '#space' nothing displays. Is my code organised correctly? I've seen examples with script tags in the body as well as or instead of the head tag..

Comment: Creating an off-line HTML5 app with CSS3 and jQuery etc. is not a trivial exercise. I would respectfully suggest that if you don't know the basics of jQuery, you get those under your belt first (plenty of great tutorials and documentation out there), then move on to coding whole apps.