# Parse Json file with Jquery ? not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova

I am trying to parse json file in my phonegap application. after searching on Stackoverflow I found this code

here is my code

```
  $.getJSON('http://shobingg.com/cms/sites/php/message.json',
  function(data)
  {    
      $.each(data, function(i, item) {
          alert (item.message);
      });
      //$("#div-my-table").append("&lt;/table>");
  });
```

you can see the original post from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097783/trying-to-parse-json-file-with-jquery)

what is the problem with my code?

Comment: Is `http://shobingg.com/cms/sites/php/message.json` returning a an array?

Comment: your cross domain request will be blocked check the firebug console

Comment: Cross domain shouldnt be an issue with Phonegap.

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: @Adam, the remote site (shobbing.com) should allow this request from a different origin isn't it?

Comment: There is not any problem with your code, the json that is returned is not a valid json which can be parsed properly. Your link returns `[{message:"This code has already been expired"}]` instead of `[{"message":"This code has already been expired"}]` where `message` should be enclosed in quotes as well....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url =  "http://www.shobingg.com/cms/sites/php/message.json";
    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Refered from [jsonp with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681466/jsonp-with-jquery)

Comment: your code is not working .. all I want is to alert the message from the json file check the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4xunG/)